# What are the class features of a cleric with the Death Domain? Where could I find this?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric

I've seen that in the 'gods and goddesses' list in the PHB, some of the gods/goddesses are part of the Death Domain. But the PHB never says anything about the Death Domain.

What are the class features of the Death Domain clerics? Where could I find them?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has 5 downvotes. "My book has a reference, but it doesn't seem to be in the book" seems a perfectly fine question... especially when it turns out to actually not be in the book as the answer says.

Comment: For those who down voted: not everyone buys a copy of the DMG.  The PHB tends to be the entry portal - or the gateway drug    - for those who buy books. (On the other hand, I think that DDB generic is searchable for some content like that, and if the down vote is for "lack of research" there is probably some grounds for that).

Comment: @nvoigt Googling “what book has death domain cleric” immediately returns the answer to this question. The downvote tooltip specifies lack of research, and it does not appear that any research occurred before this question was posted.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I agree in that not everyone owns on, but OP did say in another question they owned it. The downvotes may be from a consistent lack of research across questions, regardless of whether or not that is fair or reasonable for this one.

Comment: @NautArch That makes sense ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Death Domain is an optional cleric subclass in the DMG.

Chapter 4 of the DMG has a section called “Villainous Subclasses” (p. 96):

> You can use the rules in the Player’s Handbook to create NPCs with classes and levels, the same way you create player characters. The class options below let you create two specific villainous archetypes: the evil high priest and the evil knight or antipaladin.
>
> The Death Domain is an additional domain choice for evil clerics, and the Oathbreaker offers an alternative path for paladins who fall from grace. A player can choose one of these options with your approval.

The subclass features are described there. It is non-SRD content, so I am not going to reproduce them here.

Comment: Is there a specifc page?

Comment: 96, it’s in the answer.